# Which algorithm is appropriate?

Tags: algorithm

Consider that the agent is a robot that moves physically inside the labyrinth. It does not
know the map of the labyrinth but it can sense its own orientation, which ways are open out of its
current square and it knows that the exit is in the lower right corner. The robot wants to reach the
exit as fast as possible. Which algorithm would you use?

My professor said that Depth First Search with modifications would be the solution. These modifications would be; remember what we searched to avoid an infinite loop and give a higher priority for moves that go to the right or down.

My understanding of DFS however is that it is not optimal and is not guaranteed to find a solution. I know that A* would find the path that cost the least but speed I am unsure.

If it helps the grid is 10x10.

Comment: `My understanding of DFS however is that it is not optimal and is not guaranteed to find a solution`. It guarantees that it will find you a solution, it's just not optimal. The board is small enough for BFS. Try it.

Comment: "My understanding of DFS however is that it is not optimal and is not guaranteed to find a solution" - your understanding is mistaken or at least incomplete. You always have to give context for "optimal". Are there multiple solutions? What are you trying to optimize for? DFS is guaranteed to find a solution provided that one exists and there are no loops in your graph. "reach the exit as fast as possible" - what does as fast as possible mean, the shortest path or the least amount of computation to find the path?

Comment: Breadth first is good at finding the optimal path, by "jumping" to the next most likely node to solve for. A robot cant just jump in the maze, so unless he sees the entire map without moving around, he is pretty much confined to a dfs solution - hence your professors claims. Remeber, it takes a lot of time to move around in the physical world...

Comment: Technically, this sounds like a maze rather than a labyrinth.

Answer (score 1):

First, DFS would find a solution if one exist (assuming it doesn't go in circles, which your professor addressed). Your assertion that this is not guaranteed is wrong.

Second, the priority directions are essentially what A* is about - it expands the path that is most likely to lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depth First Search, if implemented correctly with the suggested modifications, will find the solution for the problem you described. You mention that the agent should reach the exit *as fast as possible* which probably meant *with the shortest path*. In this sense DFS is not optimal because it will return the first path to reach the exit. [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) will find the shortest path. A* and its variants are the preferred way to solving path-finding problems like you described and have been used in real-time computer games for decades.

Comment: As fast as possible includes finding the path, not finding the shortest path

Comment: That is true, I was referring to to the wording: "The robot wants to reach the exit as fast as possible" which in the physical world would imply the shortest (safe) path. Thanks for your improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I will use A* with an appropriate heuristic function adjusted from the characteristic of labyrinth. Both DFS, BFS and A* will find the solution. But with proper heuristic function, A* will find the solution faster.